# How do I create a 2d array of room exits (-1 = no exit) for a movement method?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[][] exits = {
                {-1, -1, -1, -1},
                {-1, -1, -1, -1},
                {-1, -1, -1, -1},
                {-1, -1, -1, -1}
             }
```

I have constant variables defined for `NUMBER_OF_ROOMS` as the total number of rooms in my dungeon(8 elements in `String[] array`). I created tables for my `String[] rmDescription` array and my `int[][] exits` array. Constants for 
`final int NORTH = 0;` `final int EAST = 1;` `final int WEST = 2;` and `final int SOUTH = 3;`

Am I correct in saying this?

Above is the initialized 2 dimensional array for a smaller scale dungeon with the elements initialized to null.  As the player moves, the values of the elements change depending on the exits that can be taken.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Did you already learn [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)?

Comment: I am learning OOP in school,...Specificallly Java.  We covered objects but the way this exercise words everything                 is confusing

Comment: It's because the best way to do this is to place this attr in a object. But if your exercise is about arrays, you could see what your professor said in last lesson to see in what method to get it work, you could do this with matrix, maps, objects, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a tempRoom variable and run a while loop that allowed a player to quit if they wanted to.  The array would swap out the "column" array's room number in the 2d array by using the user input's direction to change the "column that they wanted to move to.  If valid, they would move and currentRoom would be roomExits[i][newRoom] which would really be the new i and j coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, as Gaspar stated, OOP would be a great way to complete this task.  As you stated, you don't want to have a lot of stuff in your main, as you have it now, you have to keep copying the room data in you main to allow for movement.  Also, a method that tracks your current position could reduce some of the options that could be presented to the user, i.e. if you are in Cell Block B you should want the user to get prompted with the you are in the southern cell, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I just registered an account here on StackOverflow so I am getting used to the formatting and rules.  I added methods and classes that start getting the job done, but I'm not sure if it is considered using arrays.  If the program works, that's my main goal.  There are two professors that have differing views on how the homeworks are supposed to be done and they are extremely difficult to get ahold of.